# Can an AWS Token-Based Authorizer Know the "Resource" (the Endpoint)?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-authorizer

I have an AWS token-based Authorizer. I can retrieve the user (i.e., the 'sub' claim) from the token but it seems impossible to retrieve the endpoint.

I am using C# and the C# authorizer handler is passed a `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest`, which contains a `RequestContext` which has a `ResourcePath` property. This all sounds promising. Unfortunately, the `RequestContext` is always null.

Is there a configuration option to populate the `RequestContext`? What's the point of having a `RequestContext` property if it's always null?

Comment: "it seems impossible to retrieve the endpoint". Which endpoint are you referring to?

Comment: @possum The REST endpoint that the Authorizer is checking authorization to.

Comment: Ensure that your API Gateway method is configured to use Lambda Proxy integration. This can be done in the API Gateway console by selecting the method, going to the Integration Request section, and choosing Lambda Proxy integration. This setup is crucial because it allows API Gateway to pass the entire request, including the RequestContext, to your Lambda function